# Is username/password authenticated SSL email with System.Net.Mail possible

Tags: authentication, ssl, system.net.mail

I read [here](http://systemnetmail.com/faq/4.5.aspx) that it's not possible to send SSL emails via System.Net.Mail if the server requires username/password authentication:

> Due to what I believe is a bug in System.Net.Mail you *cannot* use SSL
>   and Credentials (username/password) at the same time. I was never able
>   to get that to work. I always got an exception from the remote mail
>   server. I believe it has to do with the steps System.Net.Mail takes to
>   initiate the SSL session and SMTP authentication.

I don't want to spend the rest of the week trying to get it to work if it's impossible. Can the SO community please corroborate this claim with an upvoted answer, or say how to do it?

P.S. According to Rackspace email services phone tech support, their secure.emailsrvr.com host on port 465 supports Explicit SSL. But so far I've been unable to send SSL emails via that server using the `System.Net.Mail` libraries, though my attempts do succeed with a trial version of a third-party library, so I know it's not our firewall blocking the port.